# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPackageManager()

Tags: android, android-context, android-package-managers

I am trying to retrieve the list of installed apps in android. I have written the following code:

```
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
myIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List AppsList = Context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0);
```

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getPackageManager() from the type Context
```

Knowing that both `Context` and `PackageManager` are abstract classes, cannot resolve the error. Kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
final List AppsList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an instance of context to call this method.
Generally when you are in an activity or a service, the context is `this`or `getContext()`. You should use this technique to :

- open new sceens
- access ressources inside an activity.
- everything else that is "local" to the current activity

If you want a more global context, you can use `getApplicationContext()`, this is useful if you want for instance, access an embedded database.

Answer (score 1):

> Knowing that both Context and PackageManager are abstract classes

Use an instance of a concrete subclass of `Context`, such as `Activity`.

Since your code probably is already in a method on a subclass of `Context`, change the problematic line to:

```
final List AppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(myIntent, 0);
```

If, for some reason, your code shown above is not in a method on a subclass of `Context`, you will need to pass in some `Context` instance to wherever this code resides, and call `getPackageManager()` on it.